# Hibernate 4 TransactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate

Currently I am using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager` and `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` in my application. I'm using declarative transaction management and I have `@Transactional` annotated method at service with `timeout=25`. I'm calling a stored procedure in it through dao layer.
My transaction is not getting timed out after defined seconds.

I want to timeout the DB call after 25 seconds because we have 30 seconds of UI request timeout. So when there is any request which takes more than 30 second at stored procdedure side, UI request gets timeout.

//Configuration

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list> //package names
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

// Service Layer

```
@Service
public class MyService
{

    @Autowired
    private MyDao             dao;

    @Transactional(timeout=25)
    public int getCountByCriteria(Crieria criteria)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(26000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dao.callProcedure(criteria, criteria.getValue(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: It will be better to attach it to the question.

Comment: I am not able to attach code. Giving me validation error that post has mostly code. Please add more details

Comment: @AndriiAbramov: My code is posted now, Please check it.

Comment: Can someone please look into it.

Comment: Add your hibernate properties also is this the method you are calling directly or is this being called from another transactional method!

Comment: I am calling it directly from Spring component method which is not transactional